# ID returned after insert is different from that of query

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been inserting a record, during which i parsed the returned id using following code

```
    Uri movieUri = mContext.getContentResolver()
            .insert(MoviesContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

    long movieRowId = ContentUris.parseId(movieUri);
```

When i am querying the database and dumping the cursor, the displayed _ID field value is different.

Please explain, if those two IDs are to be treated different or they are the same.

Here is the Content Provider code

```
public class MoviesProvider extends ContentProvider{

    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();
    private MoviesDbHelper moviesDbHelper;

    static final int ALLMOVIES = 100;
    static final int SPECIFICMOVIE = 101;

    static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
        final UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        final String authority = MoviesContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;
        uriMatcher.addURI(authority, MoviesContract.PATH_MOVIES, ALLMOVIES);
        uriMatcher.addURI(authority, MoviesContract.PATH_MOVIES + "/#", SPECIFICMOVIE);
        return uriMatcher;
    }




 @Override
        public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
            final SQLiteDatabase db = moviesDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            final int match = uriMatcher.match(uri);
            int rowsUpdated;

        switch(match) {
            case ALLMOVIES:
                rowsUpdated = db.update(MoviesContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME,values,selection,selectionArgs);
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }
        if (rowsUpdated != 0) {
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
        }
        return rowsUpdated;
    }

@Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = moviesDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = uriMatcher.match(uri);
        Uri returnUri;

        switch(match) {
            case ALLMOVIES:
                long _id = db.insert(MoviesContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                if (_id > 0) {
                    returnUri = MoviesContract.MovieEntry.buildMovieUri(id);
                }
                else {
                    throw new android.database.SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return returnUri;
    }
```

MovieContract.java

```
public class MoviesContract {

    public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.moviesapp";
    public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);
    public static final String PATH_MOVIES = "movies";

    public static final class MovieEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendEncodedPath(PATH_MOVIES).build();
        public static final String CONTENT_DIR_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_MOVIES;
        public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_MOVIES;
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "movie";
        public static final String COLUMN_MOVIE_TITLE = "original_title";
        public static final String COLUMN_POSTERPATH = "poster_path";
        public static final String COLUMN_SYNOPSIS = "overview";
        public static final String COLUMN_RELEASEDATE = "release_date";
        public static final String COLUMN_VOTECOUNT = "vote_count";
        public static final String COLUMN_VOTEAVERAGE = "vote_average";
        public static Uri buildMovieUri(long id) {
            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI,id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code of content provider?

Comment: @Deepesh I have added code for content provider.

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, and the returned ID at insertions should be same id of inserted row.